# Collapsible sidebar with top nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I found this basic Bootstrap dashboard template, but when on mobile there is no toggler icon. Anyone know how to change it to keep sidebar on large screens and have the very same sidebar hidden under toggler button (hamburger menu) when on mobile?

Template: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/dashboard/#

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the given bootstrap 4 classes
I made this like that:

```html
<!-- Start Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

  <!-- Start Container -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- This Button is for the toggled navigation -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Start Toggle -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"YOUR SITE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Toggle -->

  </div>
  <!-- End Container -->

</nav>
<!-- End Navigation -->
```